# SQL left join on multiple columns

Tags: sql, left-join

I got two tables as below:

First table is to store the values:

```
id | column1 | column2
-----------------------
1  | aaa     | xxx
1  | aaa     | yyy
1  | bbb     | zzz
```

Second table is to store translated values:

```
id | old      | new
-----------------------
1 | aaa       | ooo
1 | yyy       | ppp
```

and the result should be

```
id | column1 | column2
-----------------------
1  | ooo     | xxx
1  | ooo     | ppp
1  | bbb     | zzz
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: What have you already tried? This is very common question about table joining.

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [ask], [mcve], the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. This "does not show any research effort'. It does not explain what the result is supposed to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column1 and Column2 should be joined seperately. Also ISNULL or COALESCE should be used, in case there are no matching translation. Below is an example (Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/160f0/3/0)

```
CREATE TABLE ValuesTable (
    Column1 varchar(3),
    Column2 varchar(3)
);

INSERT INTO ValuesTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES
('aaa', 'xxx'), ('aaa', 'yyy'), ('bbb', 'zzz');

CREATE TABLE TranslationTable (
    Old varchar(3),
    New varchar(3)
);

INSERT INTO TranslationTable (Old, New) VALUES
('aaa', 'ooo'), ('yyy', 'ppp');

SELECT ISNULL(c1.New, Column1), ISNULL(c2.New, Column2) FROM ValuesTable 
LEFT JOIN TranslationTable c1 ON c1.Old = Column1
LEFT JOIN TranslationTable c2 ON c2.Old = Column2
```